# hide excel sheet tabs through javascript programmatically

Tags: javascript, excel, jscript, wsh, activexobject

This is my .js file .When it is run, it opens the Excel sheet.It's running perfectly.My requirement is that when the excel sheet opens,it should display only the temp_pivot tab in excel. Right now, it displays both the excel tabs viz temp_pivot and Temp. When I add the line Temp.Visible=False in the code, it actually hides the temp_pivot tab and displays the Temp tab. What could be the possible solution ?

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var xl = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
xl.Visible = true;
var wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(fso.GetAbsolutePathName("Temp.csv"));
var sheet = wb.ActiveSheet;
wb.Worksheets.Add(after=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count));
var pws = wb.ActiveSheet;
pws.Name="temp_pivot";
var pvtTable = pws.PivotTableWizard(1, varSource=wb.sheets("temp").Range("A1").CurrentRegion);
pvtTable.PivotFields("DECISIONYEAR").Orientation = 1;
pvtTable.PivotFields("DECISIONMONTH").Orientation = 1;
pvtTable.PivotFields("WEEKYEAR").Orientation = 1;
pvtTable.PivotFields("APPLICANT").Orientation = 4;
pvtTable.PivotFields("SUM OF APPLICANT").Function=-4157;
pvtTable.PivotFields("APPROVED").Orientation = 4;
pvtTable.PivotFields("SUM OF APPROVED").Function=-4157;
pvtTable.PivotFields("SOURCE").Orientation = 3;
pvtTable.PivotFields("PRODUCTCOLOR").Orientation = 3;
pvtTable.PivotFields("PRODUCT").Orientation = 3;
pvtTable.PivotFields("SUB_CHANNEL_CADM").Orientation = 3;
pvtTable.PivotFields("CHANNEL_CADM").Orientation = 3;
pvtTable.PivotFields("MARKET").Orientation = 3;
pvtTable.PivotFields("OFFER_TYPE").Orientation = 3;
pvtTable.DataPivotField.Orientation=2;
pws.Columns.Autofit;
pws.Rows.Autofit;
xl.DisplayAlerts =0;
xl.DisplayAlerts = 1
xl.CutCopyMode = 0;
xl.EnableEvents = 0;
xl = null;
```

---

Also, Windows Script Host throws an error saying 'Temp' is undefined. The source being Microsoft JScript runtime error and Code being 800A1391

Comment: Oh no! Don't use ActiveX! Is there really no other way to do this?

Comment: Why shouldn't ActiveX be used?

Comment: It is browser specific, often a security risk. A lot of companies disable them because of this, so your code will not run at all any more.

Comment: But it's running perfectly just as I mentioned. My only requirement is to hide one of the Excel tabs.

Comment: You should add the code that fails to your question. It's hard to imagine a wrong approach only to fix it. The failure could be due to a number of factors.  Also worth noting, you can use a 1-based index to hide the tab. I.e (VBA, not JS) `Sheets(1).Visible = -1 'xlVisible` or `Sheets(1).Visible = 0 'xlHidden` or `Sheets(1).Visible = 2 'xlSheetVeryHidden`

Comment: @enhzflep: can u please explain the above code ? My file is basically a Javascript code.

Comment: @Partic: The `wsh` tag means the OP runs this code as a Windows script (using wscript/cscript) and not inside IE.

Comment: I still have no clue how to use Sheets(1).Visible = -1 'xlVisible or Sheets(1).Visible = 0 'xlHidden or Sheets(1).Visible = 2 'xlSheetVeryHidden. Please enlighten me !

Comment: Try to use `ws.Sheets("temp").Visible=0;`